# data-* attributes do not work with Html::a() in Yii 2

Tags: yii2, custom-data-attribute

I have the following:

```
Html::a('Link', ['some/route'], [
    'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary',    // WORKS
    'style' => 'padding: 100px;',           // WORKS
    'data-id' => 123,                       // DOES NOT WORK
    'data' => [
        'id' => 123,                        // DOES NOT WORK
    ],
]);
```

As per [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#a()-detail), both of the specified `data-*` attributes in `Html::a` helper should render their respective attributes in the HTML output, but they do not, and I do not understand why.

Yii 2 documentation on [renderTagAttributes](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#renderTagAttributes()-detail) also states the following:

> **Renders the HTML tag attributes.**
>
> Attributes whose values are of boolean type will be treated as boolean
>   attributes.
>
> Attributes whose values are null will not be rendered.
>
> The values of attributes will be HTML-encoded using encode().
>
> The "data" attribute is specially handled when it is receiving an
>   array value. In this case, the array will be "expanded" and a list
>   data attributes will be rendered. For example, if 'data' => ['id' =>
>   1, 'name' => 'yii'], then this will be rendered: data-id="1"
>   data-name="yii". Additionally 'data' => ['params' => ['id' => 1,
>   'name' => 'yii'], 'status' => 'ok'] will be rendered as:
>   data-params='{"id":1,"name":"yii"}' data-status="ok".

---

**EDIT:** I am trying to do this inside `GridView` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, since I have used `Html::a` inside a `GridView` column, you will have to change the output format of that column. `html` will not work for data attributes, so you will need to switch to `raw`:

```
[
    'label' => 'Actions',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return Html::a('Link', ['some/route'], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary',    // WORKS
            'style' => 'padding: 100px;',           // WORKS
            'data-id' => 123,                       // WORKS
            'data' => [
                'id-second' => 123,                 // WORKS
            ],
        ]);
    },
]
```